# Apache Tika - how to get all parsers?

Tags: java, apache, parsing, apache-tika

I'm trying to use Apache Tika to parse content of document. But instead of retrieving document's content I've got empty String. When I check which parser was used by calling `metadata.get("X-Parsed-By")` I allways get only `org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser`.

This is my code:

```
private String parseToString(byte[] content) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    parser.parse(TikaInputStream.get(content), handler, metadata);

    return handler.toString();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have tika-parsers in classpath?

Comment: If you mean tika-parsers.jar - I have.

Comment: If only [Apache Tika provided a handy troubleshooting guide, including details of how to check which parsers are available, and how to fix that](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#Identifying_what_Parsers_your_Tika_install_supports). Oh, no, wait, it does, and you just ignored it :(

Comment: @Gagravarr Where is apache-tika there is you 

Comment: @DupinderSingh You can have stackoverflow email you when there are new questions to tags you are interested in :)